# Posting to "me/myapp:myaction" results in my open graph story only displaying in my 'recent activity' section

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my open graph story to also appear on my timeline and be seen on the news feed. I authorize the user by calling

```
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email", @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {//some handler code}
```

And post my open graph story by calling

```
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
    action[@"event"] = myEventUrlString;

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/myapp:myaction" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {//some handler code}
```

The call is successful and I get an id back but what I am consistently seeing is that my open graph story is not appearing on my timeline, not appearing in the news feed and only seems to show in the 'recent activity' section of my page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "explicitly share" your action for it to appear on the user's timeline: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/

Be sure to read the "Inappropriate use" section of that page to ensure you're meeting the guidelines.

Once you enable it for your action in the app settings, you should do something like the following to enable it per action:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
action[@"event"] = myEventUrlString;
action[@"explicitly_shared"] = @"true";
```

Comment: This seems correct but is not working for me. Does your action have to be approved before the 'explicitly_shared' functionality works?